# How can I emulate 'grep -B' functionality in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, grep

I have been searching for a solution that allows me to search the lines of an array, and if a string match is made, push that line and the 2 previous lines into an array. It seems this would be easily done using the `grep` command. However, I cannot get this to work. This is what I have:

```
sub ipsearch {
    my $ip = $_[0];
    my @IPVSCONFIG =  grep (/\W+virtual\s$ip\s/, @RAWDATA);
}
```

Is it possible to add the "-B 2" syntax to the grep command? I've tried several forms of this syntax but I cannot get it to work:

```
@IPVSCONFIG =  grep -B 2 (/\W+virtual\s$ip\s/, @RAWDATA);
```

Please let me know if this is even possible, and what the correct syntax should be. If you have any other suggestions, please let me know.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: This comes long after, but for future readers: [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44493583/4653379)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick is to identify the lines where the match occurs, then identify the relevant indices around:

Get the matched indices:

```
my @matchedIndices = grep { $RAWDATA[$_] =~ /\W+virtual\s$ip\s/ } 2 .. $#RAWDATA;
```

Get the indices around:

```
my @wantedIndices  = map { ( $_-2 .. $_ ) } @matchedIndices;
```

And take an array slice:

```
my @IPVSCONFIG = @RAWDATA[ @wantedIndices ];
```

Putting it altogether in a Schwartzian transform:

```
my @IPVCONFIG = map  { @RAWDATA[$_-2..$_] }
                grep { $RAWDATA[$_] =~ /\W+virtual\s$ip\s/ }
                2 .. $#RAWDATA ;
```

Definitely a much busier solution than the traditional command-line `grep -B 2`!

Comment: @Zaid You can probably reduce it to `... = map @RAWDATA[$_-2 .. $_], grep ...`

Comment: @Zaid - as I noted in comment to TLP's answer, there's one benefit from his approach. For a very large file, his code can be easily adapted to scan through the file only once and not store it - **without** wasting both O(N) memory to store `@RAWDATA` and doing twice the work traversing the data (one on splitting the file into `@RAWDATA` array and one on `grep`).

Comment: @DVK : Agreed, though the OP gave me an array to work with up front so I'm guessing that's not really an issue here.

Comment: I'm just stumbling upon the term Schwartzian transform which is IMO used only in context of sorting, which is not done here. Decorate-sort-undecorate.

Comment: @KarstenS. : It doesn't have to be `sort`-ing to be a Schwartzian transform. The idea behind Schwartzians is to eliminate temporary variables by chaining together `map`, `grep` and `sort` to achieve in one assingment what would otherwise take a few extra helper variables.

Answer (score 3):

A basic version of your subroutine. I assume you wanted to return the list when done with it. Untested.

```
sub ipsearch {
    my $ip = shift;
    my @IPVSCONFIG = (); # no matches should be empty list, not undef
    my @buffer = ()      # to avoid undef warnings
    for (@RAWDATA) {
        push @buffer, $_;
        shift @buffer if @buffer > 3;
        if (/\W+virtual\s$ip\s/) {
            push @IPVSCONFIG, @buffer;
            @buffer = ();
        }
    }
    return @IPVSCONFIG;
}
```

Comment: @DVK Actually, he scans the data only once. Unless you count `map $RAWDATA[$_]` as one of the scans.

Comment: Sorry, not quite. I meant splitting up the original text into @RAWDATA as an extra scan (your point is also kind of a scan but it's O(M) where M is # of matches). Your code can just as well work with `<$filehandle>` as with `@RAWDATA`, so can be easily adapted to only scan an extra large file once. Zaid's can not. An extra++ major benefit is memory savings.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing up the grep program `/bin/grep` with the perl function named `grep` (`perldoc -f grep`). While the former takes additional parameters, like `-B`, the latter does not.