# grep 3 latest occurences and some lines around the occurence

Tags: perl, unix, grep, tail

I have a file like:

```
exception: anythinggggg...
exception: anythinggggg...
abchdhjsdhsd
ygsuhesnkc
exception: anythingggg...
exception: anything...
..
..
```

I want to grep the latest 2 occurrences of exception keyword along with 3 lines before and 3 lines after it.

I am using something like

```
grep -C 3 exception | tail -12
```

I am using tail -12 here as I want 6 lines per occurrence and latest 2 occurrences. this works fine when occurrences of exception are far off from each other but gives me useless lines if say both occurrences are consecutive.

```
abdgjsd
abdgjsd
abdgjsd
abdgjsd
abdgjsd
abdgjsd
abdgjsd
abdgjsd
exception
exception
exception
abcd
```

In the above case, it gives me

```
abdgjsd
abdgjsd
abdgjsd
exception
exception
exception
abcd
```

however, what I want is

```
abdgjsd
exception
exception -----------------> OUTPUT FOR FIRST OCCURRENCE
exception
abcd

abdgjsd
abdgjsd
exception-----------------> OUTPUT FOR SECOND OCCURRENCE
exception
exception
abcd
```

Is there another way to this? Probably something in whch I can also specify the number of occurrences and not just grep lines and tail some output from it.

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output **for that** sample input to your question.

Comment: It is already specified in the question..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output you get is because `grep` stops printing context (`-C`) at the next match. I don't see how to make it behave otherwise.

The script below (written on the command-line) reads the whole file and forms an array of lines. Then it goes through it and prints surrounding two lines for each match, or up to start/end of array.

```
perl -MList::Util=min,max -0777 -wnE'
    @m = split /\n/; 
    for (0..$#m) { 
        if ($m[$_] =~ /exception/) { 
            $bi = max(0,$_-2); 
            $ei = min($_+2, $#m);
            say for @m[$bi..$ei]; 
            say "---" 
         } 
     }
' input.txt
```

The `---` are printed for easier reviewing of output. This prints the desired output.

The `-0777` option makes it *slurp* the whole file into the `$_` variable, which is `split` by newline. The iteration goes over the array index (`$#m` is the index of the last element of `@m`). The `$bi` and `$ei` are begin/end index to print, which cannot be +/- 2 near the beginning and end of the array.

The output can be piped to `tail` but this can't be automated: if a match is within the last two lines there'll be (one or two) fewer lines of output so input need be known for precise cut-off. Or find indices of matches in the script, `@idx = grep { $m[$_] =~ /exception/} for 0..$#m;`, and use that in the condition to only print the last two.

If you are going to use something like this I'd make it a script. Then read all lines into an array directly, provide command-line options (like `-C` in `grep`), etc.

Maintaining line-by-line processing would make the job far more complicated. We need to keep track of a match so that we can print the following lines once we read them. But here we need *multiple* such records -- for the next match(es) as well, if they come within the following lines to be printed.

Comment: @Zaid  Thank you, yes, very related!  A little screw here is about matches on lines 0,1 and -2,-1. As for making one pass and not pulling the whole file -- the other nice answer there won't work here because we'd need multiple buffers (or index counters), which is what I meant by "_far more complicated_"

Comment: There is one gripe I have with both my answer and yours: if the match occurs on consecutive lines there will be duplicate lines printed. That may be OK here, but the purist in me says that the same context should be extended in such situations

Comment: @Zaid  Well, I agree. I think that `grep`'s solution to that is rather reasonable; at least no repetitions.  This question, though, is exactly about that -- they _want_ the repeated output, they want the whole context every time. I can understand that, too, but I would not design a general purpose tool that way either, agreed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { bufSize = 5 }
{ updBuf(NR) }
/exception/ { rangeEndNrs[NR+int(bufSize/2)] }
NR in rangeEndNrs { prtBuf(NR) }
END { prtBuf(NR+1) }

function updBuf(nr) {
    buf[((nr-1)%bufSize)+1] = $0
}

function prtBuf(nr,     i) {
    for (i=1; i<=bufSize; i++) {
        print buf[((nr+i-1)%bufSize)+1]
    }
    print "---"
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
abdgjsd
abdgjsd
exception
exception
exception
---
abdgjsd
exception
exception
exception
abcd
---
exception
exception
exception
abcd
abdgjsd
---
```

It works by just keeping a 5-line buffer of input lines and everywhere "exception" is found setting an indicator that 2 lines later the buffer should be printed, thus printing the "exception" line plus the 2 lines before and after it. You just need to massage it to handle the cases of "exception" occurring less than 2 lines from the start or end of the input file however you want that handled (see how the last output block above is, presumably undesirably, wrapping around the buffer since it's run off the end of the input file).